# Expand quiz (JS) to multipe choice questions

Tags: javascript

I'm happy with this script but at the moment it only accepts **one right answer** and **automatically jumps to the next question** when an answer has been selected.

Is it possible to expand the existing script easily with these features?

##### a) Accept more then only one right answer

Look at the Coke question: it should be something like

```
    solution: ['Zero','Vanilla','Cherry'], falses: ['Mud'],
```

##### b) Adding a "next question"-button

This is needed because of the new feature of a)

```js
if (!Array.from) {
    Array.from = (function () {
        var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
        var isCallable = function (fn) {
            return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
        };
        var toInteger = function (value) {
            var number = Number(value);
            if (isNaN(number)) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number)) {
                return number;
            }
            return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
        };
        var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
        var toLength = function (value) {
            var len = toInteger(value);
            return Math.min(Math.max(len, 0), maxSafeInteger);
        };
        // The length property of the from method is 1.
        return function from(arrayLike /*, mapFn, thisArg */ ) {
            // 1. Let C be the this value.
            var C = this;
            // 2. Let items be ToObject(arrayLike).
            var items = Object(arrayLike);
            // 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(items).
            if (arrayLike == null) {
                throw new TypeError(
                    "Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined");
            }
            // 4. If mapfn is undefined, then let mapping be false.
            var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
            var T;
            if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
                // 5. else
                // 5. a If IsCallable(mapfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
                if (!isCallable(mapFn)) {
                    throw new TypeError(
                        'Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function');
                }
                // 5. b. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
                if (arguments.length > 2) {
                    T = arguments[2];
                }
            }
            // 10. Let lenValue be Get(items, "length").
            // 11. Let len be ToLength(lenValue).
            var len = toLength(items.length);
            // 13. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
            // 13. a. Let A be the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method 
            // of C with an argument list containing the single item len.
            // 14. a. Else, Let A be ArrayCreate(len).
            var A = isCallable(C) ? Object(new C(len)) : new Array(len);
            // 16. Let k be 0.
            var k = 0;
            // 17. Repeat, while k < len… (also steps a - h)
            var kValue;
            while (k < len) {
                kValue = items[k];
                if (mapFn) {
                    A[k] = typeof T === 'undefined' ? mapFn(kValue, k) : mapFn.call(T,
                        kValue, k);
                } else {
                    A[k] = kValue;
                }
                k += 1;
            }
            // 18. Let putStatus be Put(A, "length", len, true).
            A.length = len;
            // 20. Return A.
            return A;
        };
    }());
}
'use strict';
var myQuiz = {
    container: null,
    // helper function
    createElement: function (o) {
        var el, p;
        if (o && (o.tag || o.tagName)) {
            el = document.createElement(o.tag || o.tagName);
            if (o.text || o.txt) {
                var text = (o.text || o.txt)
                el.innerHTML = text;
            }
            for (p in o) {
                if (!p.match(/^t(e)?xt|tag(name)?$/i)) {
                    el[p] = o[p];
                }
            }
        }
        return el;
    },
    // user interface for a quiz question
    createOptions: function () {
        var t = this,
            options = [],
            ul = document.createElement("ul");
        t.emptyContainer();
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "h2",
            text: "(" + t.currentQuestion.category + ") " + t.currentQuestion.question
        }));
        t.intoContainer(ul);
        // create options
        options.push(t.currentQuestion.solution);
        t.currentQuestion.falses.forEach(function (s) {
            options.push(s);
        });
        t.shuffleArray(options);
        options.forEach(function (s, i) {
            var li = document.createElement("li"),
                label = t.createElement({
                    htmlFor: "a" + t.questions.length + "_" + i,
                    tag: "label",
                    text: s
                }),
                radio = t.createElement({
                    id: "a" + t.questions.length + "_" + i,
                    name: "answer",
                    tag: "input",
                    type: "radio",
                    tabindex: "0",
                    value: s
                });
            ul.appendChild(li);
            li.appendChild(radio);
            li.appendChild(label);
        });
        // Hinweis für Tastatur-User
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "button",
            text: "confirm choice",
            type: "submit"
        }));
    },
    currentChoices: [],
    currentQuestion: null,
    // data could be filled from an external source (JSON)
    data: [{
        
        category: 'Capitals',
        question: 'What is the capital of Canada?',
        solution: 'Ottawa',
        falses: ['Berlin', 'New York', 'Sidney'],
        explanation: '...'
    }, {
        category: 'Food',
        question: 'What Coke flavors do exist?',
        solution: 'Zero',
        falses: ['Vanilla','Cherry','Mud'
            ],
        explanation: '...'
    }],
    emptyContainer: function () {
        var t = this;
        while (t.container.firstChild) {
            t.container.removeChild(t.container.firstChild);
        }
    },
    handleInput: function () {
        var t = this, // t points to myQuiz
            // create real array so we can use forEach
            inputs = Array.from(t.container.getElementsByTagName("input")),
            selectedSolution = "";
        // determine selection
        inputs.forEach(function (o) {
            if (o.checked) {
                selectedSolution = o.value;
            }
        });
        // process selected answer
        if (selectedSolution && t.currentQuestion) {
            t.currentChoices.push({
                a: selectedSolution,
                q: t.currentQuestion
            });
            t.play();
        }
        // accept start button
        if (!t.currentQuestion) {
            t.play();
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        var t = this;
        // here goes any code for loading data from an external source
        t.container = document.getElementById("quiz");
        if (t.data.length && t.container) {
            // use anonymous functions so in handleInput
            // "this" can point to myQuiz
            t.container.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
                t.handleInput();
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
            t.container.addEventListener("mouseup", function (ev) {
                // we want to only support clicks on start buttons...
                var go = ev.target.tagName.match(/^button$/i);
                // ... and labels for radio buttons when in a game
                if (ev.target.tagName.match(/^label$/i) && t.currentQuestion) {
                    go = true;
                }
                if (go) {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        t.handleInput();
                    }, 50);
                    ev.stopPropagation();
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    },
    intoContainer: function (el, parentType) {
        var t = this,
            parent;
        if (!el) {
            return;
        }
        if (parentType) {
            parent = document.createElement(parentType);
            parent.appendChild(el);
        } else {
            parent = el;
        }
        t.container.appendChild(parent);
        return parent;
    },
    // ask next question or end quiz if none are left
    play: function () {
        var t = this,
            ol;
        // game over?
        if (!t.questions.length) {
            t.showResults();
            // offer restart
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                t.start();
            }, 50);
            return;
        }
        t.currentQuestion = t.questions.shift();
        t.createOptions();
    },
    // list with remaining quiz question objects
    questions: [],
    // list original questions and given answers and elaborate on solutions
    showResults: function () {
        var cat, ol, s, scores = {},
            t = this,
            tab, thead, tbody, tr;
        t.emptyContainer();
        // show message
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "p",
            text: "You've answered all questions of this quiz. Here are your results:"
        }));
        // list questions and given answers
        ol = t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            id: "result",
            tag: "ol"
        }));
        t.currentChoices.forEach(function (o) {
            var p, li = ol.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "li"
            }));
            // list original question
            li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                className: "question",
                tag: "p",
                text: "(" + o.q.category + ") " + o.q.question
            }));
            // list given answer
            p = li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "p",
                text: "Your answer: "
            }));
            p.appendChild(t.createElement({
                className: (o.q.solution == o.a ? "correct" : "wrong"),
                tag: "em",
                text: o.a
            }));
            // wrong answer?
            if (o.q.solution != o.a) {
                p = li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "p",
                    text: "The right answer should be: "
                }));
                p.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "em",
                    text: o.q.solution
                }));
            }
            // elaborate on solution?
            if (o.q.explanation) {
                p = li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "p",
                    text: "Explanation (why): "
                }));
                p.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "em",
                    text: o.q.explanation
                }));
            }
        });
        // display a kind of percentual score over the categories
        cat = [];
        t.currentChoices.forEach(function (o) {
            if (!cat.includes(o.q.category)) {
                cat.push(o.q.category);
            }
        });
        cat.sort();
        cat.forEach(function (c) {
            var correct = 0,
                num = 0;
            t.currentChoices.forEach(function (o) {
                if (o.q.category == c) {
                    num++;
                    if (o.q.solution == o.a) {
                        correct++;
                    }
                }
            });
            scores[c] = Math.floor(100 * correct / num) + "%";
        });
        tab = t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            id: "scores",
            tag: "table"
        }));
        tab.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "caption",
            text: "Overview categories"
        }))
        thead = tab.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "thead"
        }))
        tr = thead.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "tr"
        }))
        for (s in scores) {
            tr.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "th",
                text: s
            }));
        }
        tbody = tab.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "tbody"
        }))
        tr = tbody.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "tr"
        }))
        for (s in scores) {
            tr.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "td",
                text: scores[s]
            }));
        }
        // show message
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "p",
            text: "Do you want to restart?"
        }));
    },
    
    shuffleArray: function (a) {
        var i = a.length;
        while (i >= 2) {
            var zi = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
            var t = a[zi];
            a[zi] = a[--i];
            a[i] = t;
        }
        // no return argument since the array has been
        // handed over as a reference and not a copy!
    },
    // start quiz with a start button
    start: function () {
        var t = this;
        // fill list of remaining quiz questions
        t.questions = [];
        t.data.forEach(function (o) {
            t.questions.push(o);
        });
        t.shuffleArray(t.questions);
        t.currentChoices = [];
        t.currentQuestion = null;
        // install start button
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            className: "startBtn",
            tag: "button",
            text: "Start quiz!"
        }), "p");
    }
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    myQuiz.init();
});
```

```css
h1 {
    background: #f1f3f4 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    padding: 1rem !important;
}

#quiz ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#quiz li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#quiz label {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fffbf0;
    border: 2px solid #e7c157;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    margin: 0.1em 0;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-align: start;
    max-width: 33em;
}

#quiz label:hover {
    background-color: #dfac20;
}

#quiz input:checked ~ label,
#quiz input:focus ~ label {
    background-color: #dfac20;
    border-color: #866a00;
}

#quiz input {
    left: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
}

#quiz button:not(.startBtn) {
    display: none;
}

#quiz button,
#quiz label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* listing with solutions */

.question {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.correct {
    color: #0c0;
}

.wrong {
    color: #c00;
}

.correct:before {
    content: '✓';
    color: #0d0;
}

.wrong:before {
    content: '✗';
    color: #f00;
}

.correct:before,
.wrong:before {
    font: 2em bold;
    padding: 0 0.2em;
}

#scores,
#scores td,
#scores th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Quiz</h1><main id="main"><form id="quiz" action=""></form></main>
```

Comment: Have you already tried to replace `type: "radio"`by `type: "checkbox"`?

Comment: There lots of additional task to be done, change the type string to an array for correct answers and so long.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `solution` from a string to `solutions` as an array and then use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to have multiple correct answers.

```js
if (!Array.from) {
    Array.from = (function () {
        var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
        var isCallable = function (fn) {
            return typeof fn === 'function' || toStr.call(fn) === '[object Function]';
        };
        var toInteger = function (value) {
            var number = Number(value);
            if (isNaN(number)) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (number === 0 || !isFinite(number)) {
                return number;
            }
            return (number > 0 ? 1 : -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(number));
        };
        var maxSafeInteger = Math.pow(2, 53) - 1;
        var toLength = function (value) {
            var len = toInteger(value);
            return Math.min(Math.max(len, 0), maxSafeInteger);
        };
        // The length property of the from method is 1.
        return function from(arrayLike /*, mapFn, thisArg */ ) {
            // 1. Let C be the this value.
            var C = this;
            // 2. Let items be ToObject(arrayLike).
            var items = Object(arrayLike);
            // 3. ReturnIfAbrupt(items).
            if (arrayLike == null) {
                throw new TypeError(
                    "Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined");
            }
            // 4. If mapfn is undefined, then let mapping be false.
            var mapFn = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void undefined;
            var T;
            if (typeof mapFn !== 'undefined') {
                // 5. else
                // 5. a If IsCallable(mapfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
                if (!isCallable(mapFn)) {
                    throw new TypeError(
                        'Array.from: when provided, the second argument must be a function');
                }
                // 5. b. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
                if (arguments.length > 2) {
                    T = arguments[2];
                }
            }
            // 10. Let lenValue be Get(items, "length").
            // 11. Let len be ToLength(lenValue).
            var len = toLength(items.length);
            // 13. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
            // 13. a. Let A be the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method 
            // of C with an argument list containing the single item len.
            // 14. a. Else, Let A be ArrayCreate(len).
            var A = isCallable(C) ? Object(new C(len)) : new Array(len);
            // 16. Let k be 0.
            var k = 0;
            // 17. Repeat, while k < len… (also steps a - h)
            var kValue;
            while (k < len) {
                kValue = items[k];
                if (mapFn) {
                    A[k] = typeof T === 'undefined' ? mapFn(kValue, k) : mapFn.call(T,
                        kValue, k);
                } else {
                    A[k] = kValue;
                }
                k += 1;
            }
            // 18. Let putStatus be Put(A, "length", len, true).
            A.length = len;
            // 20. Return A.
            return A;
        };
    }());
}
'use strict';
var myQuiz = {
    container: null,
    // helper function
    createElement: function (o) {
        var el, p;
        if (o && (o.tag || o.tagName)) {
            el = document.createElement(o.tag || o.tagName);
            if (o.text || o.txt) {
                var text = (o.text || o.txt)
                el.innerHTML = text;
            }
            for (p in o) {
                if (!p.match(/^t(e)?xt|tag(name)?$/i)) {
                    el[p] = o[p];
                }
            }
        }
        return el;
    },
    // user interface for a quiz question
    createOptions: function () {
        var t = this,
            options = [],
            ul = document.createElement("ul");
        t.emptyContainer();
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "h2",
            text: "(" + t.currentQuestion.category + ") " + t.currentQuestion.question
        }));
        t.intoContainer(ul);
        // create options
        options.push(...t.currentQuestion.solutions, ...t.currentQuestion.falses)
        t.shuffleArray(options);
        options.forEach(function (s, i) {
            var li = document.createElement("li"),
                label = t.createElement({
                    htmlFor: "a" + t.questions.length + "_" + i,
                    tag: "label",
                    text: s
                }),
                radio = t.createElement({
                    id: "a" + t.questions.length + "_" + i,
                    name: "answer",
                    tag: "input",
                    type: "radio",
                    tabindex: "0",
                    value: s
                });
            ul.appendChild(li);
            li.appendChild(radio);
            li.appendChild(label);
        });
        // Hinweis für Tastatur-User
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "button",
            text: "confirm choice",
            type: "submit"
        }));
    },
    currentChoices: [],
    currentQuestion: null,
    // data could be filled from an external source (JSON)
    data: [{
        
        category: 'Capitals',
        question: 'What is the capital of Canada?',
        solutions: ['Ottawa'],
        falses: ['Berlin', 'New York', 'Sidney'],
        explanation: '...'
    }, {
        category: 'Food',
        question: 'What Coke flavors do exist?',
        solutions: ['Zero', 'Cherry', 'Vanilla'],
        falses: ['Mud'
            ],
        explanation: '...'
    }],
    emptyContainer: function () {
        var t = this;
        while (t.container.firstChild) {
            t.container.removeChild(t.container.firstChild);
        }
    },
    handleInput: function () {
        var t = this, // t points to myQuiz
            // create real array so we can use forEach
            inputs = Array.from(t.container.getElementsByTagName("input")),
            selectedSolution = "";
        // determine selection
        inputs.forEach(function (o) {
            if (o.checked) {
                selectedSolution = o.value;
            }
        });
        // process selected answer
        if (selectedSolution && t.currentQuestion) {
            t.currentChoices.push({
                a: selectedSolution,
                q: t.currentQuestion
            });
            t.play();
        }
        // accept start button
        if (!t.currentQuestion) {
            t.play();
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        var t = this;
        // here goes any code for loading data from an external source
        t.container = document.getElementById("quiz");
        if (t.data.length && t.container) {
            // use anonymous functions so in handleInput
            // "this" can point to myQuiz
            t.container.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
                t.handleInput();
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
            t.container.addEventListener("mouseup", function (ev) {
                // we want to only support clicks on start buttons...
                var go = ev.target.tagName.match(/^button$/i);
                // ... and labels for radio buttons when in a game
                if (ev.target.tagName.match(/^label$/i) && t.currentQuestion) {
                    go = true;
                }
                if (go) {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        t.handleInput();
                    }, 50);
                    ev.stopPropagation();
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    },
    intoContainer: function (el, parentType) {
        var t = this,
            parent;
        if (!el) {
            return;
        }
        if (parentType) {
            parent = document.createElement(parentType);
            parent.appendChild(el);
        } else {
            parent = el;
        }
        t.container.appendChild(parent);
        return parent;
    },
    // ask next question or end quiz if none are left
    play: function () {
        var t = this,
            ol;
        // game over?
        if (!t.questions.length) {
            t.showResults();
            // offer restart
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                t.start();
            }, 50);
            return;
        }
        t.currentQuestion = t.questions.shift();
        t.createOptions();
    },
    // list with remaining quiz question objects
    questions: [],
    // list original questions and given answers and elaborate on solutions
    showResults: function () {
        var cat, ol, s, scores = {},
            t = this,
            tab, thead, tbody, tr;
        t.emptyContainer();
        // show message
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "p",
            text: "You've answered all questions of this quiz. Here are your results:"
        }));
        // list questions and given answers
        ol = t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            id: "result",
            tag: "ol"
        }));
        t.currentChoices.forEach(function (o) {
            var p, li = ol.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "li"
            }));
            // list original question
            li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                className: "question",
                tag: "p",
                text: "(" + o.q.category + ") " + o.q.question
            }));
            // list given answer
            p = li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "p",
                text: "Your answer: "
            }));
            p.appendChild(t.createElement({
                className: (o.q.solutions.includes(o.a) ? "correct" : "wrong"),
                tag: "em",
                text: o.a
            }));
            // wrong answer?
            if (!o.q.solutions.includes(o.a)) {
                p = li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "p",
                    text: "The right answer should be: "
                }));
                p.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "em",
                    text: o.q.solutions.join(', ')
                }));
            }
            // elaborate on solution?
            if (o.q.explanation) {
                p = li.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "p",
                    text: "Explanation (why): "
                }));
                p.appendChild(t.createElement({
                    tag: "em",
                    text: o.q.explanation
                }));
            }
        });
        // display a kind of percentual score over the categories
        cat = [];
        t.currentChoices.forEach(function (o) {
            if (!cat.includes(o.q.category)) {
                cat.push(o.q.category);
            }
        });
        cat.sort();
        cat.forEach(function (c) {
            var correct = 0,
                num = 0;
            t.currentChoices.forEach(function (o) {
                if (o.q.category == c) {
                    num++;
                    if (o.q.solutions.includes(o.a)) {
                        correct++;
                    }
                }
            });
            scores[c] = Math.floor(100 * correct / num) + "%";
        });
        tab = t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            id: "scores",
            tag: "table"
        }));
        tab.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "caption",
            text: "Overview categories"
        }))
        thead = tab.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "thead"
        }))
        tr = thead.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "tr"
        }))
        for (s in scores) {
            tr.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "th",
                text: s
            }));
        }
        tbody = tab.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "tbody"
        }))
        tr = tbody.appendChild(t.createElement({
            tag: "tr"
        }))
        for (s in scores) {
            tr.appendChild(t.createElement({
                tag: "td",
                text: scores[s]
            }));
        }
        // show message
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            tag: "p",
            text: "Do you want to restart?"
        }));
    },
    
    shuffleArray: function (a) {
        var i = a.length;
        while (i >= 2) {
            var zi = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
            var t = a[zi];
            a[zi] = a[--i];
            a[i] = t;
        }
        // no return argument since the array has been
        // handed over as a reference and not a copy!
    },
    // start quiz with a start button
    start: function () {
        var t = this;
        // fill list of remaining quiz questions
        t.questions = [];
        t.data.forEach(function (o) {
            t.questions.push(o);
        });
        t.shuffleArray(t.questions);
        t.currentChoices = [];
        t.currentQuestion = null;
        // install start button
        t.intoContainer(t.createElement({
            className: "startBtn",
            tag: "button",
            text: "Start quiz!"
        }), "p");
    }
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    myQuiz.init();
});
```

```css
h1 {
    background: #f1f3f4 none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
    padding: 1rem !important;
}

#quiz ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#quiz li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#quiz label {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fffbf0;
    border: 2px solid #e7c157;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    margin: 0.1em 0;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    text-align: start;
    max-width: 33em;
}

#quiz label:hover {
    background-color: #dfac20;
}

#quiz input:checked ~ label,
#quiz input:focus ~ label {
    background-color: #dfac20;
    border-color: #866a00;
}

#quiz input {
    left: -9999px;
    position: absolute;
}

#quiz button:not(.startBtn) {
    display: none;
}

#quiz button,
#quiz label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* listing with solutions */

.question {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.correct {
    color: #0c0;
}

.wrong {
    color: #c00;
}

.correct:before {
    content: '✓';
    color: #0d0;
}

.wrong:before {
    content: '✗';
    color: #f00;
}

.correct:before,
.wrong:before {
    font: 2em bold;
    padding: 0 0.2em;
}

#scores,
#scores td,
#scores th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Quiz</h1><main id="main"><form id="quiz" action=""></form></main>
```